# Forcasting gains or losses on Forex

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange, forecasting

I am using FXCM brokers to invest in Forex. I would like to know if there is a way to forecast our equity when we have open trades if the rates go up or down to a certain level.
I am using FXCM Trading Platform but can switch to MT4 .

Comment: You should plan to lose between 80% and 100% of your money with Forex speculation.

Comment: Thanks @PeteB. DO you mean in this case that I should close my demo account now and move on to do something else with my money?